# updating wrong record in database after pressing button

Tags: php, post, submit

I am busy making a new website, but I ran into a little problem today.

I will try to explain it as good as possible.

My website displays a random message every time you refresh the page, you can then click a button that says you like that message.

Now the problem is that when you click the button to like the message the page reloads (because of the form tag) and the like will go to the next message that is displayed.

I have no idea how to solve this so I hope you guys out there can help me with this.

I will post the code below here:

The bit that updates the database after you pressed the like button:

```
    if(!empty($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $id = $random['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE `quotes` SET `likes` = likes + 1 WHERE `id` = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ((mysql_error()!=""))
        {
            $ANTW = mysql_error();
            echo ("Cause of the error: " . $ANTW);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "It worked!";
        }
}
```

The like button:

```
<form name='' method='post' action=''>
 <input class='like' type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

I hope that this if enough for you to solve the problem, if not let me know and I will post more code.

Dennis

UPDATE:

Hi guys, Thanks for all of the quick and good advice it worked the way you told me. Thanks

Comment: Why `$id = $random['id'];` Why would you use a random ID?

Answer (score 1):

Save your id in a hidden input:

```
<form name='' method='post' action=''>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $random[$id]; ?>" name="like" />
    <input class='like' type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

And in your PHP code assign:

```
$id = $_POST['like']; // your like id you passed by the form (input type hidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the id in submit form using a hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="myid" value="YOURID">
```

and in the next page fetch the previous id using

```
$_POST['myid']
```